# How to correct the objection about dymanic Object type by FlexPMD?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, pmd, flex-pmd

I have the code in one of my flex file used as labelFunction in a DataGrid.

When I run the `FlexPMD` to do the code review, it generates an objection about the dynamic type object used in the following method signature and it suggests to use strongly type object.

```
  public function getFormattedCreatedTime(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String { 
    var value:Date=item[column.dataField];
    return dateFormatter.format(value);
  }
```

Does anyone know how to rectify it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in your question - just use a strongly type object, or perhaps an interface if `item` can have various types.

But basically there's nothing wrong with using dynamic type objects as long as you know what you're doing. I'd say just ignore the error.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would be of course possible to type item to something less generic than Object, but some times you can't, or Object is exactly the right type, in this case you can use `//NOPMD` comment - it will instruct the PMD validator to skip the definition. Of course the good practice is to also explain the reason you used `//NOPMD`.